# Swype "The Swype package you installed is configured for another device." error on install

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid, cyanogenmod, swype

Running CM6 on my Motorola Drid.

Another Swype upgrade, another headache.

I keep getting this error message when I uninstall --> reboot --> reinstall Swype: "The Swype package you installed is configured for another device."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently I was closing out of the install app too early.  When you install Swype (the actual app, not the installer), and press done, you must WAIT about 2 to 4 seconds for a dialog box to appear to "Enable Swype".  DO NOT PRESS BACK (and then try to enable Swype via the keyboards in Settings) because it will not work!  Swype has to show this dialog box in order to create a license file.  [More info here](http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?1511-The-Swype-package-you-installed-is-configured-for-another-device...&p=8449#post8449).